# Find Files Recursively With Different ACLs

Tags: files, permissions, acl, file-search

How would I go about finding all files recursively that have ACLs different from what I'm searching for?  For example I would like to find all files in a directory that have ACLs that are not identical to the following example:

```
# owner: bob
# group: bobs-group
user::rwx 
user:fred:rwx
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

Using a separate search I'd like to be able to do the same for directories, but with slightly different permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `find` and a `diff`.

1. Save the desired reference permissions in a file, e.g. `perref`

---

```
$cat perref
# owner: bob
# group: bobs-group
user::rwx 
user:fred:rwx
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

2. Do some `find`-magic by simply comparing the output of `getfacl` with the reference and negating matches. As this needs to cut the first line of `getfacl` output (i.e. the filename), one needs process substitution here, this must go via a shell script and proper quoting.

---

```
find -type f \
! -exec bash -c 'diff -q <(getfacl "$1" | sed 1d ) perref >/dev/null' bash '{}' \; \
-print
```

Or `-print0` in the end, depending on the further plans. This works as `diff` has a 0 as exit status if files are identical.

Remove the `!` for finding files with matching ACLs.
Use `-type d` for doing the search on directories.

Comment: Just checking, isn't that "process substitution" rather than "command substitution"?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds You are right. Corrected. To clarify for others: `$(command)` or `\`command\`` => command substitution ; `<(command)` or `>(command)` => process substitution.

Comment: I suggest to use `cmp -s` instead of `diff -q`. That way, you can omit `>/dev/null`. I also suggest to change the `<(…)` process substitution by a pipe (`getfacl … | cmp -s - perref`), which will allow you to use `sh -c` instead of Bash. The result of the second line is `! -exec sh -c 'getfacl "$1" | sed 1d | cmp -s - perref' sh '{}' \;` :-)

Comment: The changes I suggested reduced the execution time on my machine by more than 50%. :-)

Comment: yet another note: write `getfacl -- "$1"` to allow for filenames starting with dashes